# HTTP request to challonge API returns error 422

Tags: javascript, api, http

I'm trying to create a tournament using api.challonge.com

When attempting to do so in node.js, it works fine with this code:

```
request.post("https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments.json", {
    "json":{
        "api_key":API_KEY,
        "name":"MyTourney",
    }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

However, when attempting to do it with an XMLHttpRequest in javascript, I am getting error 422. This is the code:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("api_key", API_KEY);
fd.append("name", "MyTourney");
        
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments.json", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send(fd);
```

I don't understand why the request is successful in the node request, but not in the XMLHttpRequest

Here is a screenshot of the browser console:

[image: browser console]

Comment: Is there an error in the browser console?

Comment: https:// username:api-key@api.challonge.com/v1/ I saw this real quick, is it of use?Weird link had to add a space!

Comment: when using that irregular link, nothing seems to happen, and onreadystatechange doesn't even log anything.

Comment: From the docs it seems like it accepts "tournament[name]" as parameter, also, I don't know why are you sending it as form-data, you should send JSON data and set header to `Content-Type: application/json` -> again in the docs: " you may also set your request headers to accept application/json, text/xml or application/xml"

Comment: Ah, "tournament[name]" instead of "name" did the trick! I still don't understand why the node version works, but thanks.